# How can a array adapter<String>, which is the following

Tags: android, listview, font-face

How can a array adapter, which is the following:

1-
.....extends ArrayAdapter

2-

```
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;    
int layoutResourcetext;
List<String> Favorites_strings;
Typeface tf;
```

3-

(this, R.layout.row_layoutfavorites, R.id.textt, Favorites_strings,"fonts/Mj_Beirut.TTF")

Comment: Your question could use a little more details and clarity if you want to get help on SO.

Comment: I have an application programming favorites and would like to listview in such a way that I can set the font, but I can not change it and now I want to build a custom array adapter the problem I fix this code my favorites

Comment: You might want to consider switching to ViewHolder with RecyclerViewer as opposed to the old ListView. Here is an example https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AFavorites extends Activity {

TextView TextViewonvan;
EditText search;
EditText editTextSearch;
TextView textviewonvanehdialog;
TextView textviwedialogmessag;
ImageButton imagebutton;

public int Subjects_total_number;
public Globals global = new Globals();
public List<String> Favorites_numbers;
public List<String> Favorites_strings;
String each_subject;

 public String[] Subjects;


TextView onvan;
TextView population;
Typeface tf;
// List view
private ListView lv;

// List view Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
CustomAdapter adapter1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.favorites);

       tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Mj_Beirut.TTF");
       onvan=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewonvanf);
       onvan.setTypeface(tf);
       onvan.setText("favorites ");
       search=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsearchh);
       imagebutton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibsearchh);



    Favorites_strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Favorites_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    final SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Subjects_total_number = global.Subjects_total_number;
    for(int x = 0; x < Subjects_total_number+1; x = x+1) 
    {  
         each_subject = "subject_" + String.valueOf(x);

        if(b)
        {
            String this_subject = "subject_" + String.valueOf(x);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(this_subject, "string", getPackageName());
            Favorites_strings.add(getResources().getString(resID));
            String x_string = String.valueOf(x);
            Favorites_numbers.add(x_string);

        }
    }



    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewf);


    // Adding items to list view
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layoutfavorites, R.id.populationf, Favorites_strings);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}